# How to recognize a key is pressed in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, key

I want to write an app. and I need to know which function is use to for get a key from keyboard input. in other wise how to recognize a key is pressed in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement following method to track down KeyEvents in J2ME,

```
protected void keyPressed(int key)
{
    int keyCode = getGameAction(key);

          switch ( keyCode )
          {
                case FIRE : 
                {
                   .
                   .
                   . 
                }
                break;

               .
               .
               .
          }
}
```

for more information have a look at to this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/Canvaskeypressedandkeytypedevents.htm)

Comment: The keyCode is what is received by keyPressed(). Calling the GameAction-code for keyCode is a bit misleading. It should be keyPressed(int keyCode) and int gameActionCode = getGameAction(keyCode)